# Traversing back up through shallow nested resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested, ruby-on-rails-5

If an application honors shallow routing, which truncates resources as they are traversed, how can previously accessed objects be traveled back to? Does it require deeply nested routes?

For example, say we have something like

```
resources :basement, shallow: true do 
  resources :lower_level do 
    resources :mid_level do 
      resources :top_level do 
        resources :roof do 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And let's assume that each basement has multiple lower_levels and each lower_level has multiple mid_levels, etc.

Once the user clicks through the lower levels and eventually arrives at the roof, how is he able to go back to, say, the associated mid_level since the :mid_level_id is not available in top_level/:top_level_id/roofs route path?

This type of situation becomes immediately noticeable even in rather simply scenarios... Once the user decides to edit a roof, the route path contains just roof/:roof_id. How can a proper redirect be issued to go back to the index of top_level's roofs (ie top_level/:top_level_id/roofs) if the previous id's are "lost"?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably your `Roof` model has a foreign key linking it to the `TopLevel`.  If so, the `Roof` record that is pulled from the database has an attribute `top_level_id` that can be used in the rendered page.